# Pass date from datepicker in JSP to select records from database

Tags: html, jsp, datepicker

I am creating a JSP page to select records from Oracle database between two date ranges and display on a HTML page . Created a JSP page and trying to pass date through datepicker is not returning any records. The datatype in Oracle DB is date

Added Java parsing, changed the date picker formats etc but none of those working. Any help appreciated.

My code as below

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");                  

        java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");
        java.util.Date da = format.parse(from_date);
        String to_date=request.getParameter("to_date");
        java.text.DateFormat format1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");
        java.util.Date ta = format1.parse(to_date);
        java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");

        select * from table 1actual_start between '"+da+"' and '"+ta+"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below `code snippet` will give you date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format then you can passed this to `jsp` page and put it in your `select` query.

```js
$('#d1 , #d2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
       Date1: <input type="text" name="ab" id="d1" />
        Date2: <input type="text" name="ab1" id="d2" />
```

Then in your `jsp` page do like below :

```
    java.sql.Date d1=null;
  java.sql.Date d2=null;
    //getting date
    String ab=request.getParameter("ab");
     String ab1=request.getParameter("ab1");
    //putting date it in below format i.e:dd-MM-YYYY 
     SimpleDateFormat s1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
            try {
                java.util.Date date1=s1.parse(ab);
              //d1 will have your correct format date                
                d1=new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(YourClassname.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            try {
                java.util.Date date2=s1.parse(ab1);
              //d2 will have your correct format date                
                d2=new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime());
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(YourClassname.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

         //pass d1 & d2 in your query 
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(" select * from table1 where actual_start between ? and ? ");

             ps.setDate(1,d1);
             ps.setDate(2,d2);
             ResultSet data =ps.executeQuery();
            while(data.next()){

           //do something
           }
```

Comment: I changed the code and getting the error - The method setDate(int, Date) is undefined for the type Statement. I tried with java.util.date and java.sql.date, but not working.

Comment: Are you using `PreparedStatment`  or not because this method belong to `preparedstatment` ?

Comment: Ok i am using Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); and calling that in the ResultSet.

Comment: You need to use `PrepareStatment` like i have did in above code

Comment: No...getting the below error. Tried with and without java.util and java.sql libraries - The import java.sql.Date collides with another import statement